# bnlearn: Extract probabilitiy estimates from network continuous predictors and discrete outcome

Tags: r, bnlearn

I am trying to make a classification network where I need to predict a categorical/discrete outcome based on a large number of continuous predictor variables. I can predict the class after learning the model, but is there a way to extract the probabilities associated with each predicted class?

Usually when the trained model consists entirely of discrete variables, you can pass `pred = TRUE` to `predict()` function, but this is not the case with a mixed model. I can't seem to find any helpful documentation on how to accomplish this (or something similar or comparable) with a mixed network.

```r
library(bnlearn)

# Create learning data ----
train <- data.frame(matrix(runif(13600), ncol = 136, nrow = 100))
train <- cbind(train, data.frame(class = rep(c("one","two","three","four"), 25)))

# Create test data ----
test <- data.frame(matrix(runif(1360), ncol = 136, nrow = 16))
test <- cbind(test, data.frame(class = rep(c("one","two","three","four"), 4)))
# m$class = rep(c("one","two","three","four"), 4)

# Create network
train_network <- mmhc(train)
train_fit = bn.fit(train_network, train)

# Make predictions
pred <- predict(train_fit, "class", method = "bayes-lw", data = test)

pred_df <- cbind(pred, data.frame(actual = test[, "class"]))
head(pred_df)

pred actual
1   one    one
2   one    two
3   two  three
4   one   four
5 three    one
6  four    two
```

Ideally, I would be able to get the predicted probabilities for each observation, e.g.,

```r
pred actual prob
1   one    one  0.67
2   one    two  0.44
3   two  three  0.32
4   one   four  0.10
5 three    one  0.11
6  four    two  0.55
```

Comment: I don't think so (at least you never used to be able to). What you can do is generate a sample from the posterior using `cpdist` and use this to get the probabilities. (ps I'm sure that you noticed but just in case .. the class variable will not have any parents)